# Keras open images and create a batch with them

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have the following function for reading images from the SO:

```
from keras.preprocessing import image as kimage
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

def read_image(path):
    img = kimage.load_img(path, target_size=(224, 224))
    tmp = kimage.img_to_array(img)
    tmp = np.expand_dims(tmp, axis=0)
    tmp = preprocess_input(tmp)
    return tmp
```

And I create the following data generator that basically iterates my path strings and call the previous function. I want to call read image function and stack its output into a numpy array that I can input to keras fit function. I am using this code:

```
batch_holder = np.zeros((batch_size, 224, 244, 3))
for j, row in batch.iterrows():
    batch_holder[j, :] = read_image(row['path'])[0]
```

But this does not work and I am receiving the following error which I consider as impossible to interpret:

> File "train.py", line 71, in data_generator
>       batch_holder[j, :] = read_image(row['path'])[0] ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (224,224,3) into shape
>   (224,244,3)

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: its a keras module, I edited my question to add it

Comment: Can you post a complete example, including preprocess_input etc..

Comment: I am sorry, it's another keras function I forgot to add the imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you written 244 instead of 224 by mistake maybe?

batch_holder = np.zeros((batch_size, 224, **244**, 3))

Comment: So easy to see... and so much time spent in here! Good catch!