# datagenerator made on python whit keras is too slow, how to improve it speed?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

i made a datagenerator for a multi input model using this two references

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/47623/how-feed-a-numpy-array-in-batches-in-keras

[Keras open images and create a batch with them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51209000/keras-open-images-and-create-a-batch-with-them)

so my generator looks like this

```
def load_data(df,path,position):
    X_numerical = []
    X_img = []
    Y = []

    for i in df.index.values:
        # read one or more samples from your storage, do pre-processing, etc.
        # for example:
        basePath = os.path.sep.join([path, "{}-*".format(i)])
        LiqPaths = sorted(list(glob.glob(basePath)))
        img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(LiqPaths[0], target_size=(100, 100))
        img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
        img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
        
        x=np.asarray(df.iloc[i]).astype('float32')
        x=tf.expand_dims(x, axis=-1)
        
        y = position[i]

        
        X_numerical.append(x)
        X_img.append(img)
        Y.append(y)
    return [np.array(X_numerical), np.array(X_img)], np.array(Y)
```

this is the generator

```
def batch_generator(df, path, position, batch_size):
    batch=[]
  #  print(len(df.index.values))
    while True:
            for i in df.index.values:
                batch.append(i)
                if len(batch)==batch_size:
                    yield load_data(df,path,position)
           batch=[]
```

and my model is this one

```
input_data = Input(name="input_numerical",shape=(2,1,))

x1  = LSTM(
        units = 1024, 
        return_sequences=True
        )(input_data)
x1  = LSTM(
        units = 1024, 
        return_sequences=False
        )(x1)


input_img = Input(name="input_images",shape=(60,30,3,))

x2 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), name="first_conv", activation='relu', input_shape=(60, 30, 3))(input_img)
x2 =MaxPooling2D((2, 2),name="first_pooling")(x2)
x2 =Conv2D(256,  (3, 3),name="second_conv", activation='relu')(x2)
x2 =MaxPooling2D((2, 2),name="seccond_pooling")(x2)
x2 = Flatten(name="flatten",)(x2)
x2 =Dense(1024, name="first_dense", activation='relu')(x2)

merge1  =concatenate([x1,x2], axis = 1)
x3 =Dense(1024,name="seccond_dense", activation='relu')(merge1)
output_liq =Dense(1,name="output", activation='sigmoid')(x3)

model = Model([input_img,input_data], output_liq)
model.summary()

tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    model, show_shapes=True
)

model.compile(
              loss="BinaryCrossentropy", 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=1e-6),
              metrics=["BinaryAccuracy"])

history = model.fit(gen,
                         epochs= 30, 
                         shuffle=False,
                         batch_size=256
                         #validation_data=([val_img, test_numerical1], val_y)
                         )
```

but it is to slow, to much i think, so i would like to know if you know how to make it perform faster, my dataset is about 44k pictures and a pandas whit 44k rows whit 2 features, i hope you can helpme

Comment: Can you add some code for what exactly `gen` is? It's likely slow because you're using for loops and loading all data into memory. I will create a `tf.dataset` if I'm able to reproduce your example

Comment: hi! i think that the gen is in the question, in the first part of the code, i edited it to make it more visible, the yield generator is named batch_generator, or did i miss something important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried creating some dummy images and a much smaller model (shown below) to try and compare performances. I took only 10 images to send through the `gen` function you built, and it took about 8 minutes to run. I'm not 100% sure why the gen function is this slow. It probably has to do with the for loops.

```
img_paths = np.arange(10)
x_nums = np.random.randn(10,2).tolist()
positions = np.arange(10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'img_paths':img_paths,
                   'nums':x_nums,
                   })

path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Stack Overflow/Images - 60,30,3/'
gen = batch_generator(df,path,positions,5)
```

---

I tried to recreate your workflow to an extent to use tensorflow-datasets. I used a smaller model with 1.8 million parameters instead of 35 million as defined by you

```
input_data = tf.keras.layers.Input(name="input_numerical",shape=(2,1,))

x1  = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
        units = 128, 
        return_sequences=True
        )(input_data)
x1  = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
        units = 128, 
        return_sequences=False
        )(x1)


input_img = tf.keras.layers.Input(name="input_images",shape=(60,30,3,))

x2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), name="first_conv", activation='relu', input_shape=(60, 30, 3))(input_img)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),name="first_pooling")(x2)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256,  (3, 3),name="second_conv", activation='relu')(x2)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2),name="seccond_pooling")(x2)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(name="flatten",)(x2)
x2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, name="first_dense", activation='relu')(x2)

merge1  = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis = 1)([x1,x2])
x3 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64,name="seccond_dense", activation='relu')(merge1)
output_liq = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,name="output", activation='sigmoid')(x3)

model = tf.keras.models.Model([input_img,input_data], output_liq)
model.summary()
```

### The total run time of `tf.data.dataset` was 35 seconds for 1 epoch having 10,000 images compared to 8 minutes for 10 images using the `gen` function

---

Here I have created the necessary inputs as best as I could. I do not understand how exactly you are getting the images, but I have just put the image paths inside the dataframe

```
path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Stack Overflow/Images - 60,30,3/'

img_paths = os.listdir(path)
x_nums = np.random.randn(len(img_paths),2).tolist()
positions = np.random.randint(0,2,len(img_paths))


df = pd.DataFrame({'img_paths':img_paths,
                   'nums':x_nums,
                   })
```

---

Next we create the tensorflow dataset

```
def preprocess(x,y):
  img = tf.io.read_file(x[0])
  img = tf.io.decode_png(img, channels=3)
  img = tf.cast(img,dtype=tf.float32)
  img = img / 255.

  x_num = tf.expand_dims(x[1],1) #You might have to change this line depending on how your data looks
  return (img,x_num),y

def dataset_gen(df,basepath,positions,batch_size):
  img_paths = tf.constant([basepath+i for i in df.img_paths])
  x_numerical = tf.constant([np.array(x) for x in df.nums.values])
  
  train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(((img_paths,x_numerical),positions))
  train_dataset = train_dataset.map(preprocess)
  train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)

  return train_dataset

train_data = dataset_gen(df,path,positions,128)
```

You can then just plug this data into the model

```
model.compile(
              loss="BinaryCrossentropy", 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=1e-6),
              metrics=["BinaryAccuracy"])

history = model.fit(train_data,
                         epochs= 1
                         #validation_data=([val_img, test_numerical1], val_y)
                         )
```

Comment: @mimus Can you please accept the answer if it helped or let me know how I can improve it?

Comment: thanks man sorry i was a little bussy, it solve the problem when the X has only one column, but im using 5 cols, should i change the preproces return to (img,x_num[0],x_num[1],...),y? or i should make it (img,x_(num[0],x_num[1],...) ),y thanks for the help

Comment: If your model has 5 different inputs, it would be (img, x_num[0], x_num[1], x_num[2], x_num[3], x_num[4]),y